# Div location behavior in IE, FF and Opera

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div in right column of my site, and for some reason it behaves weirdly in IE, FF and Opera. Yet works as intended in Chrome and Safari.

Here is the page with a problem: [link](http://compare-best-kettlebells-dvds.com/visitsite/link) .

The slider is based on slightly modified code found [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/) in case you wondering.

So the question is: why different behavior in different browsers and how to fix it?

Comment: You should post the code in question here, and describe the problem.

Comment: I guess I should also mention that this page used to act normally before until now, and similar code work as intended on other pages of site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by removing the `width="700"` attribute from the `.content2` cell. Since you already specify the table as 900 and the right cell as 200, there is no need to add the other cell's width, and it fixes the odd behaviour.

Comment: God bless you, I now remember I added width myself when was trying to fix extra pixel problem cause by "Show no-follow links" addon in chrome! Do you have a website with donate button on it? you deserved a beer for your time :)

Comment: is it the one in your profile?

Comment: The width doesnt include the margins you have set.  If you want to use a width use 640px (with 2x30px margins = 700)

Comment: If you would like to contribute to any of my projects, it would be much appreciated, but really I'm just here to help people :p